# Replace values in a matrix keeping data structure

Tags: r

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    4
[4,]    3    4
[5,]    3    6
[6,]    3    5
[7,]    6    7

structure(c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 4, 3, 4, 4, 6, 5, 7), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))
```

And a vector composed of 12,000 numbers:

```
 n <- seq_along(1:12000)
```

I would like to `sample` values in the vector and replace with them values in the matrix but keeping the same structure. Here are two examples of desired output

```
>example1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   25
[2,]   10    3
[3,]  122   25
[4,]  300   25
[5,]  300   15
[6,]  300   89
[7,]   15 1253

>example2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9    2
[2,]    9   30
[3,]   22    2
[4,]   30    2
[5,]   30    5
[6,]   30   58
[7,]    5  253
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `[]` operator, to replace all values in a matrix, e.g.:

```
your_matrix[] = sample(12000, length(your_matrix), replace=FALSE)
your_matrix
#     [,1]  [,2]
#[1,]  3051 11110
#[2,] 11003  1606
#[3,]  7518  1196
#[4,] 11621  9585
#[5,] 11044  9931
#[6,]  9717  5835
#[7,]  3577  9329
```

*EDIT:* Sorry, I misread your question. To replace the same old values with the same new values you could use a similar code:

```
# create 1:max_element random values (e.g. 1:7)
s = sample(12000, max(your_matrix), replace=FALSE)
# replace the complete matrix with the random values 
# (s[your_matrix] is the same as s[c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 4, 3, 4, 4, 6, 5, 7)])
# some values are chosen twice or triple times
m[] = s[your_matrix]
m
#      [,1]  [,2]
#[1,]  8781 11348
#[2,]  8781 11033
#[3,] 10051 11348
#[4,] 11033 11348
#[5,] 11033  7637
#[6,] 11033  1754
#[7,]  7637  8995
```

Comment: thanks @sgibb, but I would like to keep the _internal structure_ of my matrix, for example in my matrix `m[1,1]` and `m[2,1]` have the same value (`1`), so I would like that the _sample matrix_ kept the same structure with the same value on `m[1,1]`, `m[2,1]`, and so on

Comment: now it works perfectly, could you explain me a bit the code? the `max` command tells the number of elements to replace and then they are put in the matrix following the order??

Comment: @user2380782: I add some comments. `max` returns the maximum number in the matrix and ensures that our `s` gets enough elements to be indexed by `your_matrix`. Afterwards they are indexed by the order of the matrix.